# Why WordPress does not Use Separate Table for Post Types (When Registring)?

Tags: custom-post-types, database

As I understand when we **REGISTER** (I am not talking about creating custom post types) custom post type WordPress not saved it in database. It is just a code. Why WordPress does not save it on separate table?

Why WordPress does not Use separate table for register the custom post types?

```
Table name : wp_post_types

Columns : ID, Post Type (Ex : Posts, Pages, etc and custom post types) and many columns for other fields like slug, etc.
```

So WordPress can store `post_type_id` in `post_type`column of `wp_posts` table instead of post type name.

Comment: What is the development-related question?

Comment: the PHP file with the custom post type definition is already a database. then it is not very efficient to duplicate this definition in a MySQL table when this definiton file is already loaded at every PHP call

Comment: @mmm "the PHP file with the custom post type definition is already a database. " Where? Which Table?

Comment: a simple file can be a database without tables. if you use a database with more functionalites like queries, schemas or tables, this is called "database management system" like MySQL or PostgreSQL

Comment: the answer to the question is "because". Someone had to make a decision and made it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be a challenge to hunt down a specific moment in time when that particular decision had been made.

My educated guess would be that storing CPT definitions persistently would complicate how they interact with rest of APIs (especially Rewrite and localization).

WP is also relatively conservative with database structure. CPT are relatively young and still evolving API, it would be a mess to try and have database table keep up with all developments of its arguments.